# Windows Path as an argument

Tags: arguments, filepath

I am developing an application in C# to encrypr/decrypt files. I have used file association to invoke decryption application on clicking the encrypted file. 
So code 'Application.ExecutablePath + " %1"'enables that.

%1 gives the FullName of the file. If the filename doesnt have spaces in it its works properly but if it have spaces like "C:\Folder Name\Encrypted File.enc" is received as "C:\FOLDERNAM~1\ENCRPTEDFIL~1".

How to get that File name Correctly correctly?

Comment: but it works despite the path seems strange to you, right? It's just converted to an **8.3 filename**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Answer (score 0):

does this piece of code do what you need?

```
private string GetLongFileName(string shortName)
{
    return new FileInfo(shortName).FullName;
}
```